# Programatically zoom out webpage in webbrowser

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my application I have created a webbrowser in which the page loads in Zoomed view.I need the page in zoomout position in default.Is it possible.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is with Javascript. You can run the script from C#.

Here you have a sample:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/08/26/calling-javascript-functions-in-windows-phone-7.aspx